# Sort Command on tabular data with empty cells

Tags: command-line, sort

While `-k` option in `sort` command helps to sort the data by given column but below example which is not perfectly tabular is still sorted by the column. How does it do it ? Which character it assumed in place of empty cells ?

```
test@ubuntu:~/Documents$ cat file1
a b c
d
e

test@ubuntu:~/Documents$ sort -k 2 file1
d
e
a b c
```

Comment: The "empty cells" are empty *strings*, and the empty string (`""`) sorts before any non-empty string in a lexicographical sort. There's no need to assume any character.  This feels like a leading "trick" question -- sorry if you're genuinely confused and I'm just too suspicious ;-)

Comment: @UncleBilly I disagree. If you perform `cat -A file`, you will see that the entire line of d and e are `d$`, `e$`.

Comment: @shr what are you disagreeing with?

Comment: @UncleBilly If I understand correctly, you say *"The "empty cells" are empty strings"*, I interpret that they are no empty strings, the line has ended.

Comment: @shr the OP is already (correctly) assuming that "missing cells" are treated as "empty cells". The question doesn't seem to be about that.

Comment: @UncleBilly all comes down, in my opinion, on how does `sort` treats a file like OP is posting. Running `sort -k 2 --debug file1` doesn't seem that `sort` sees empty cells. I might be wrong interpreting the output this way.

Comment: @shr yes, it does, even if the implementation does NOT have to handle them explicitly. it's even explicitly stated in the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sort.html): "[`-k`] shall define a key field that begins at `field_start` and ends at `field_end` inclusive, unless `field_start` falls beyond the end of the line or after `field_end`, in which case the key field is *empty*."

Answer (score -1):

Sort command sorts file assuming the contents are ASCII. So null must have been used there.